# How to rewrite a fold with anonymous function in Haskell into a regular function?

Tags: haskell, lambda, functional-programming, fold, currying

I am trying to teach myself functional programming using Haskell.

I have hard time understanding currying and lambdas.

This is a function that generates a list of prfixes of a list (outputs a list of lists).

```
foldr (\element accumulator -> [] : map (element:) accumulator) [[]]
```

I am trying to rewrite it as a regular function without lambda to help me understand how lambdas work. How would I do it? I am stuck. Would I need a helper function? Thank you.

Comment: If the fold abstraction confuses you, express it by mere recursion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you will need a helper function.  `where` clauses are a great place to put helpers like this.  `where` clauses are attached to a *definition*, so I will need to name your function (I have named it [`inits`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:inits)). Start by just moving the expression out verbatim.

```
inits :: [a] -> [[a]]
inits = foldr helper [[]]
    where
    helper = \element accumulator -> [] : map (element:) accumulator
```

Then you can move the lambda arguments on the right to parameter bindings on the left, which means the same thing:

```
inits :: [a] -> [[a]]
inits = foldr helper [[]]
    where
    helper element accumulator = [] : map (element:) accumulator
```

*(You can also just do one parameter:*

```
    helper element = \accumulator -> [] : map (element:) accumulator
```

*These are all equivalent.)*

Comment: @noobie See Will Ness’s answer below.

Comment: @noobie, `where` is just a convenience to help you organize your namespace. It could also be done with `let` or at the top level.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like you're looking for a [pointfree](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree) form. Yes, it can be done.

```hs
inits :: [a] -> [[a]]
inits = foldr ((([]:).) . map . (:)) [[]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtBCoAgFET3nWKIFrqoAwh1gY4gf/EhQ8lU0s5vH5rFDAzvea6Xi7H3kEKrMAaWCfMGK0vD/644czweKKUsGb1oLLi5SCujtaBE/eaQBDzyAEl5QmqY8Pvj7l/x2VXX/Ng/)

Your lambda has turned into `(([]:).) . map . (:)`. Not very pretty, huh? And *much* more difficult to understand. I suggest you shy away from this approach.

Answer (score 0):

In general,

```
foldr g [[]] []            =  [[]]
foldr g [[]] [a,b,c, ...]  =  g a (foldr g [[]] [b,c, ...])
```

Your function `g` is `( \ x y ->  [] : map (x:) y )` i.e.

```
                    g x y  =  [] : map (x:) y
```

Thus with your `g` we have

```
foldr g [[]] [a,b,c, ...]  =  [] : map (a:) (foldr g [[]] [b,c, ...])
```

Replacing `foldr g [[]]` with just `foo`, and pseudocode `[a,b,c, ...]` with the valid pattern `(a:bc)`, we get

```
foo          []            =  [[]]
foo          (a:bc)        =  [] : map (a:) (foo           bc       )
```

which is "a regular function" without lambda and without a `where` clause.